# Why my Databaseview name appears as non found in my Dao?

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-room, android-room-relation

I dont know why but Android Studiodoesnt find my DatabaseView. Even if i install others projects

This is the DatabaseView. Its created in a class called LibroDatos.

```
package com.example.pruebaexamenroom;

import androidx.room.DatabaseView;


@DatabaseView(value = "SELECT libro.id, libro.titulo, libro.autor," +
        "libro.idCliente,cliente.name as nombreCliente FROM libro " +
        "INNER JOIN Cliente ON libro.idCliente = cliente.idHumano",
            viewName = "v_LibroDatos")

public class LibroDatos {
    public int id;
    public String Titulo;
    public String Autor;
    public int idCliente;
    public String nombreCliente;

}
```

This is the Dao. Here is where its said that doesnt exist

```
package com.example.pruebaexamenroom;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Transaction;

import java.util.List;
@Dao
public interface DaoLibro {
        @Transaction
        @Query("SELECT * FROM v_LibroDatos")
        List<LibroDatos> obtenerLibros();

        @Insert
        void InsertarLibro(Libro...libros);

        @Query("UPDATE libro SET titulo =:titulo,autor=:autor WHERE id =:id")
        void updateLibro(int id,String titulo,String autor);

        @Query("DELETE FROM libro")
        void borrarLibro();

        
}
```

This is the AppDatabase. Its all declared in here.

```
package com.example.pruebaexamenroom;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(
        entities = {Libro.class, Cliente.class},
        views = {LibroDatos.class},
        version = 1
)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract DaoCliente daoCliente();
    public abstract DaoLibro daoLibro();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can just ignore the error and that the project will compile successfully.

If while coding the obtenerLibros Query you type in v for the view you will see that it does know as it prompts to complete e.g.

[image]

but then still flags it as an error. However it compiles successfully.

**Note** if you look at the build log, then it has warnings:-

```
warning: The query returns some columns [titulo, autor] which are not used by a.a.so75347005javaroomviewnotfound.LibroDatos. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. You can annotate the method with @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns. 
a.a.so75347005javaroomviewnotfound.LibroDatos has some fields [Titulo, Autor] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: id, titulo, autor, idCliente, nombreCliente. - a.a.so75347005javaroomviewnotfound.DaoLibro.obtenerLibros()
```

So you may wish to

1. Include the `@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns` annotation
2. Rename the member variables in the **LibroDatos** class to be lower case.

for 1 :-

```
@Transaction
@RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
@Query("SELECT * FROM v_LibroDatos")
List<LibroDatos> obtenerLibros();
```

for 2 :-

```
public class LibroDatos {
   public int id;
   public String titulo; //<<<<<<<<<< was Titulo
   public String autor; //<<<<<<<<< was Autor
   public int idCliente;
   public String nombreCliente;

}
```